# Remove bits from number

Tags: math, boolean-logic

I have some bit flag, where:

```
A = 1 (0001)
B = 2 (0010)
C = 4 (0100)
D = 8 (1000)
```

I would like to set bit A and C in my flag:  flag = A | C

Now my flag is 5 (0101).

I need to delete bit C from flag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clear a flag you typically `AND` with its *complement*, e.g. in C and related languages:

```
x = 5;           // x = 0101
x = x & ~C;      // x = x & 1011 = 0101 & 1011 = 0001
```

Note: this can be expressed slightly more succinctly as:

```
x &= ~C;
```

Alternatively if you already know that a particular bit is 1 and you want to set it to 0 then you can just toggle (invert) it using XOR:

```
x = x ^ C;       // x = x ^ 0100 = 0101 ^ 0100 = 0001
```

or:

```
x ^= C;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

1) Check, is bit set

```
flag & C == C
```

2) If bit set apply XOR operation:

```
flag ^ C
```

Now my flag is 5 (0001).

May be there are more simple solutions?